# Is the homogeneous coordinate ring of a flag variety a UFD?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, lie-theory

I was wondering if $G$ is a semisimple complex algebraic group, then is the homogeneous coordinate ring of a flag variety a UFD or not?

Comment: No, except for \emph{minimal} flag varieties (e.g. Grassmannians): as soon as $\operatorname{rk}\operatorname{Pic}(V)>1  $, the homogeneous coordinate ring of $V$ is not a UFD. See Hartshorne, exer. II.6.3.c).

Comment: For type A, see Fulton's Young Tableaux, Chapter 9.